# PHP: Can't fetch an array when using a php variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch an array from a MySQL database but I can't when using a php variable ($final_date) instead of a string (2015-02-16). Can anyone help me?

Here is the code:

```
$date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$date->modify('-1 day');
$prev_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$final_date = (string)$prev_date;

function GetPrevUsers(){
    $Adname = "Error";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT users FROM stats WHERE date = '".$final_date."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $Adname  = $row['users'];
    }
    return $Adname ;
}

echo GetPrevUsers();
```

For some reason it the function works when I use the actual date instead of the php variable like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT users FROM stats WHERE date = '2015-02-16'");
```

Comment: Try echoing your query to make sure it is correct. Also, it is better to send `$final_date` as a parameter with you `GetPrevUsers()` function.

Comment: The query was right, but as you said I had to send $final_date as a parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work as the scopes are different; you try to access a variable from within your function. You could either pass the variable to the function [e.g. : `function GetPrevUsers($final_date){ yourCode }`] , or add the variable `$final_date` to the `$GLOBALS` array.

The first approach is generally the preferred one; only add variables to the `$GLOBALS` array when it's really neccessary.

Comment: Solved! Thanks a bunch! I will mark your answer as correct when the time limit is over.

Answer (score 1):

Keep `$final_date` as global, check function:

```
function GetPrevUsers(){
    global $final_date;
    $Adname = "Error";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT users FROM stats WHERE date = '".$final_date."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $Adname  = $row['users'];
    }
    return $Adname ;
}
```